# Opening another sharedpreference in save activity replaces old sharedpreferece

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

### Problem

1. I have created a `SharedPreferenceAdapter.java` which contains some frequently used connections.
2. I create two objects of `SharedPreferenceAdapter` in `same activity`, both accessing different SHARED PREFERENCE FILE. Let's say, first one is `firstadb` that opens `ABC.xml` and second one is `secondadb` that `DEF.xml`.
3. The `firstadb` is used inside my `JSONObjectRequest` and it is called when Volley responds. While, the `secondadb` is called to instantly and does its tasks and has no further use.
4. When response comes and `firstadb` does it's tasks somehow, when I attach debugger and see the files name, it is accessing `DEF.xml` and not the `ABC.xml`.

### SharedPreferenceAdapter.java

```
public class SharedPreferenceAdapter {

    static SharedPreferences main;
    static SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
    String KEY_FIRST_RUN = "first_run";
    String KEY_POSTED = "posted";
    String KEY_DEFAULT_FILENAME = "ABC";
    Context cont;
    Map<String, ?> shpf_contents;

    // I was earlier using PreferenceManager.getDefaultPreference but later changed to this code just for debugging. I use this constructor for firstadb.    
    public SharedPreferenceAdapter(Activity act){
        main = act.getSharedPreferences(KEY_DEFAULT_FILENAME, 0);
        this.cont = act;
    }

    // I use this one for secondadb
    public SharedPreferenceAdapter(Context cont, String AdapterName){
        this.cont = cont;
        main =  cont.getSharedPreferences(AdapterName, 0);
        this.shpf_contents = main.getAll();
    }

    public boolean onFirstRun(){
        edit = main.edit();
        edit.putBoolean(KEY_FIRST_RUN, false);
        return edit.commit();
    }

    public boolean onPost(String value){
        edit = main.edit();
        edit.putString(KEY_POSTED, value);
        return edit.commit();
    }

    public boolean onLoggedIn(String val){
        return saveData(Keys.usertable.USER_KEY_TOKEN, val);
    }

    public boolean isFirstRun(){
        return main.getBoolean(KEY_FIRST_RUN, true);
    }

    public String isPosted(){
        return main.getString(KEY_POSTED, null);
    }

    public String getData(String key){
        return main.getString(key, null);
    }

    public String isLoggedIn(){
        return main.getString(Keys.usertable.USER_KEY_TOKEN, null);
    }

    public boolean saveData(String key, String val){
        edit = main.edit();
        edit.putString(key, val);
        return edit.commit();
    }

    public boolean saveData(String key, int val){
        edit = main.edit();
        edit.putInt(key, val);
        return edit.commit();
    }

    public boolean saveData(String key, long val){
        edit = main.edit();
        edit.putLong(key, val);
        return edit.commit();
    }

    public boolean clearData(){
        edit = main.edit();
        edit.clear();
        return edit.commit();
    }

    public boolean clearPost(){
        edit = main.edit();
        edit.remove(KEY_POSTED);
        return edit.commit();
    }

    public void logout(){
        edit = main.edit();
        boolean success = edit.remove(Keys.usertable.USER_KEY_TOKEN).commit();
        boolean bf = main.contains(Keys.usertable.USER_KEY_TOKEN);
        this.shpf_contents = main.getAll();
        DatabaseAdapter dbadb = new DatabaseAdapter(cont);
        dbadb.open();
        dbadb.delAll(Keys.Property.PROPERTY_TABLE_NAME);
        dbadb.close();
    }
}
```

### In my ACTIVITY

```
onStart(){
    getData();
}

onResume(){
    SharedPreferenceAdapter secondadb = new SharedPreferenceAdapter(ACTIVITY.this, "DEF");
    secondadb.clearData();
}

public void getData(){
    SharedPreferenceAdapter firstadb = new SharedPreferenceAdapter(ACTIVITY.this);
    // Check if net is working
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    verify_getUserObjects(response);
                } catch (JSONException ex){
                    //TODO Something with ex
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;

                if(response != null && response.data != null){
                    try{
                        JSONObject error_obj = new JSONObject(new String(response.data));
                        verify_getUserProperty(error_obj);
                    }catch (JSONException ex) {
                        // TODO Something with ex
                    }
                }
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();

                // SOMEHOW, when isLoggedIn is called, firstadb is accessing "DEF.xml" (XML file used by secondadb)
                headers.put(KEY_AUTHORIZATION, VALUE_AUTHORIZATION+firstadb.isLoggedIn());
                return headers;
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

### WorkAround found so far

If I, instead of creating a SharedPreferenceAdapter, use SharedPreferences directly for secondadb, firstadb works fine.

Comment: static SharedPreferences main;
    static SharedPreferences.Editor edit; ---here you should not use static  your problem will be solved but lot of memory waste will happen and second your changing the reference of  "main" object that is static that is the problem so either you use the two different static object with flag for it but you need to handle properly than it may not cause the problem---- main =  cont.getSharedPreferences(AdapterName, 0);---- main = act.getSharedPreferences(KEY_DEFAULT_FILENAME, 0); in constructor of your SharedPreferenceAdapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is generated because your `SharedPreferences` and `SharedPreferences.Editor` are static, because of that, when you instantiate a new `SharedPreferenceAdapter.java` and change the editor or the shared prefs object, it will be changed for all instances and it will always have the value generated by the last call of any constructor.

Just remove the `static` keyword and everything should work properly.